# 3 types of buttons, make them add numbers

Tags: javascript, function, button, addition

Im trying to make a reservation system for a movie theather. In this system i added 3 types of buttons, the 3 buttons have a different ID. Now i want to make 1 button show 6 euro's for example. second button 8 euros, then when i click multiple buttons the prices need to add and save so i can go to the next stage of this script. I tried googling alot but all i get is freaking minceraft bullshit -.- if anyone could help thnx.

```
 <td><button onclick="kaartverkoop1()" id="kaartverkoop1">B</button></td>
<td><button onclick="kaartverkoop1()" id="kaartverkoop1">B</button></td>
<td><button id="kaartverkoop2">O</button></td>
<td><button id="kaartverkoop2">O</button></td>
<td></td
```

This is an example of 2 types of buttons. I tried to create a function for the buttons and worked with "kaartverkoop1()" the code for that is here.

```
    function kaartverkoop1(stoel, soort){
        if (document.getElementById("resultaat").innerHTML == "") {
            document.getElementById("resultaat").innerHTML = "De stoel die u heeft gekozen is :";
        }

        document.getElementById("resultaat").innerHTML+= stoel + ",";
        document.getElementById("resultaat1").innerHTML= "De prijs is ";
        document.getElementById("resultaat2").innerHTML= "De zaal die u heeft gekozen is Zaal 1 ";
        document.getElementById("bestel").innerHTML= "Bestel";
        document.getElementById("annuleer").innerHTML= "Annuleer";
        }
```

So if anyone could help me out i would be gratefull.

sincerly,

Dusan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/1qasuuap/

I would stay away from ID's when using multiple items, as you cannot have multiple ID's, it will break JavaScript:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-price]');

var buttonClicked = function (event) {
    var element = event.target;
    var price = parseInt(element.data('price'));
    var totalElement = document.querySelector('[data-total]');
    var total = parseInt(totalElement.data('total'));

    if (element.hasClass('active')) {
        element.removeClass('active');
        total = total - price;
    } else {
        element.addClass('active');
        total = total + price;
    }

    totalElement.data('total', total);
    totalElement.innerHTML = total;
};

for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
    var button = buttons[b];
    button.addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);
}
```

Use data attributes instead.

Comment: Thats exactly it thanks alot! I have been breaking my mind over this for over a week!

Comment: No problem, here is an example with a bit more flair: http://jsfiddle.net/1qasuuap/1/

Comment: Hey, srry me again. I tried adding the 3 files from Jsfiddle into a  html, js and a Css file but it doesnt seem to work. Is it because im doing somethign wrong with src? Im linking it like this     <script type="text/javascript" src="Reservatie.js"></script>

Comment: you will need to execute a `DOM ready` call, this is easily accomplished with jQuery, else here: https://code.google.com/p/domready/

Comment: It does give me the message "Dom is ready" but the script still doesnt work

Comment: Thanks figured it out